# React, error when generating tabs dynamically

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I'm implementing React tabs from this url : https://codesandbox.io/s/7mjxpo9k7x

Current code :

```
  <Tabs>
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
        <div label="Croc">
          After &apos;while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
        </div>
        <div label="Sarcosuchus">
          Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
        </div>
  </Tabs>
```

However, the label should be dynamic, so I'm using the map function for an array that I created called 'domains' in the local state as follows :

```
export class AddComponent2 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        domains: [],         

    };
}

componentDidMount() {       
    apiClient.getDomains().then(result => {
        this.setState({ domains: result });
            }); 
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Tabs>
                {this.state.domains.map(x =>
                    <div label="{x.domainCode}">
                        See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
                     </div>
                )}
            </Tabs>

        </div>
    )
}
  }
  export default AddComponent2;
```

However this results in the following error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
>
> this.state = {
>         activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
>        };

There is data in the array. When I hard code the values (as described in the example on the url) I don't have problems. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: The code in the codesandbox and in the  post seems to be very different. So, it's really unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: I modified the post

Comment: It still looks different. There's no ...domains in the codesandbox.

Comment: That's an array I made. Updated

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any hint. So, closing it. Ask clearly next  time.

Comment: Actually, I can see the issue in the code you posted in the  question. And not answering because of your codesandbox arose me with unclear stuff.

Comment: can you share the code where you init the state with  active tab  ?

Comment: I made an update of my example. Is it clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your error doesn't come from code you past, because you don't have `{ activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label};` in this code.

But I think, you try to get property you doesn't have yet, because you get props asynchronously. So.. You should check when you get response and set `activeTab` here:

```
apiClient.getDomains().then(result => {
        this.setState({ domains: result, activeTab:... });
});
```